# Volume of A Solid

Tags: calculus

I wonder if some one can clarify the confusion I have over the following problem:

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the parabolic cylinder $z = 1- y^2$, the planes $x = 0, z = 0$ and the plane $x+z = 1$. My struggle is to visualize the solid and find the set up of the triple integral for the volume.

What is your approach?

Comment: @DougM: That's a nice interpretation. I will actually do that once I am at Taco Bell so I can feel and see the solid.

Comment: I realize that I was cutting it wrong (I had z = y^2).  And every time I cut my taco the stuff fell out.  Take an apple strudel.  Cut it legthwise.  Eat half.  The half that you have left is a parabolic cylinder cut by the plane $z=0.$  Cut cross-wise.  This is the plane $x=0.$  Now at the point on the edge of the strudel where you cut $x= 0$ the point $(0,0,1)$ cut at a 45 degree angle back toward the middle of the strudel $x+z=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid is bounded by the graph of the plane $x(y,z)=1-z$ over the domain in the $yz$-plane given by the parabolic segment 
$$D=\{(0,y,z)\,:\; 0\leq z\leq 1-y^2, y\in [-1,1]\}.$$ 
Therefore
$$\mbox{volume}(D)=\iint_D (1-z) dydz=\int_{y=-1}^1\left(\int_{z=0}^{1-y^2}(1-z)dz\right) dy=\frac{4}{5}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I was not thinking enough about to use $x = 1-z$ as you did. I will accept your answer once the up votes by other users are seen and they checked to be true. I think your answer is right.

Comment: @DeepSea  Glad to be useful. I edited my answer with the final result. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your region.

[image]

The yellow bit is what is left of the parabolic cylinder.  The green bit is the plane $x+z = 1$

When $z = 0,$ The intersection with $z=1-y^2$ leaves $y^2 = 1$ or $y=1, y=-1$

As for the integral

$\int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{1-y^2}\int_0^{1-z} \;dx \;dz \;dy$

alternatively you could say:

$\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-z}}^{\sqrt{1-z}}\int_0^{1-z}\; dx \;dy \;dz$

then substiute u = 1-z

$\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{u}}\int_0^{u}\; dx \;dy \;du$

Comment: Thank you @Doug M for sketching the region that is clearly viewable. It took me close to an hour to sketch it on the white board.